# restrict firing of data grid view control validation event

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview control in winform. The datagrid view is extended to implement validating event of the grid. The problem is I have several buttons including  button named ok in my form. But, I want to validating event to be fired in ok button click. How can I restrict validating event to be fired in ok button click.

Comment: Create a bool field, only set it to true in the OK button click, and check the flag in your validation routine, resetting it back to false as appropriate: ie in the validation you have `if (! okButtonWasClicked) return else (…)`

Comment: The problem is I cannot  modify validating event of datagrid control. It's as a said is custom data grid extending datagrid control

Comment: Can you turn validation off in the custom control?